# linux login but do not get prompt

Tags: linux

Does anyone know what would cause this, for a linux system operating at run level 5 I can ssh into the system successfully regarding the password being accepted but I do not get a prompt to be given.  The system is Suse and/or SLES.

The system has been running for 5+ year on a local area network, the most simple network setup possible, no proxy, static ip address on everything.

Here is the exact process. I `ssh` in to one of 7 systems all identical, I get login: I then type my username then get my `ssh` banner printed then get `Password:` and I type my password. After that I never get anything, no prompt, no error, just hangs for 1+ hours so far all on 7 systems.

Graphical console login is disabled, only login method is over the network. There's a graphical login method via web browser over the network and that doesn't work, fall back to ssh as an admin which is pretty much always successful. After I type my password, i get no response in the putty ssh window, simply no prompt so it's a useless non functioning connection.

what would cause the basic shell prompt in bash, csh, tcsh, whatever to not come up in a terminal windows?

Comment: Does setting the prompt explicitly help, i.e. doing `PS1='$ '` once you are logged in? What shell are you using and are you starting it with any parameters?

Comment: no, system has been running for 5+ year on a local area network, the most simple network setup possible, no proxy, static ip address on everything

Comment: When you have logged in, if you type anything, is there a shell that accept what you are typing as commands?  This is unclear from the question.

Comment: I ssh in to one of 7 systems all identical, i get `login:` I then type my username then get my ssh banner printed then get `Password:` and I type my password.  After that I never get anything, no prompt, no error, just hangs for 1+ hours so far all on 7 systems

Comment: And? Does it respond to anything you are typing? If not, try transferring a minimal set of shell initialization files via `sftp` or `scp` to the account.

Comment: What gives `ssh -vvv`?

Comment: graphical console login is disabled, only login method is over the network.  There's a graphical login method via web browser over the network and that doesn't work, fall back to ssh as an admin which is pretty much always successful.  After I type my password, i get no response in the putty ssh window, **simply no prompt** so it's a useless non functioning connection

Comment: what would cause the prompt to not come up after what seems to be a successfull SSH connection?  I can open a second putty window and purposely give a wrong username and/or password and get the proper response until 3 or 5 mistakes it disconnects which is correct.  But after successfully typing password, never get a prompt

Comment: Does the remote system respond to anything you type after logging in? This is the third time I'm asking this.

Comment: `Does the remote system respond to anything you type after logging in?`  **NO**

Comment: This could sometimes happen if the remote machine is under extreme load. There would be a prompt in this case, but it may considerable time before it appears, and the shell may be virtually unusable anyway. Do you have physical access to the machines and can log in at the console?

Comment: Try logging with via a ssh client that offer verbose logging of what is going on. i.e. ssh -vvv from the command line on another server